# How to use COUNTIFS with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula that checks for the 2nd(onwards) instance of duplicate using 2 columns. I want it to be automatically applied to new rows but can't seem to figure out how to use ARRAYFORMULA for COUNTIFS. Can anybody please help me convert this formula `=COUNTIFS($K$2:$K2, $K2, $T$2:$T2, $T2)>1` to an arrayformula or something similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`MAP()` function may be a good solution. Try-

```
=MAP($K$2:INDEX($K$2:$K,COUNTA($K$2:$K)),$T$2:INDEX($T$2:$T,COUNTA($K$2:$K)),LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS($K$2:$K,x,$T$2:$T,y)>1))
```

- `K2:INDEX(K2:K,COUNTA(K2:K))` will return a array of range from `K2` to next non empty cell of `K` column.
- Same `T2:INDEX(T2:T,COUNTA(K2:K))` will return a array of range from `T` column still base on `K` column last non empty cell.

> ***Edit:*** As per comment, try below formula-

```
=INDEX(MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),C2:INDEX(C2:C,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(A2:A,x,C2:C,y,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(x))>1)))
```

> Change ranges for your sheet.

[image]

Comment: Hi! I tried using your formula but what it did was to show TRUE for all instances of duplicates based on column K & T but what I want is to show FALSE on the first instance while showing TRUE to the rest.

Comment: Share few sample data and desired output.

Comment: Try this one `=INDEX(MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),C2:INDEX(C2:C,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,y,COUNTIFS(A2:A,x,C2:C,y,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(x))>1)))`.